# Couldn't load jnifftw3: findLibrary returned null

Tags: java, android, fftw

I am trying to use FFTW library in my project.
After reading some tutorials I did next - In Android Studio, Project Structure, Dependencies I have found this library. It uploaded pretty perfect.
Some classes appeared in "External Libraries" of "Project".
I have tried to use [this](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/fftw) code:

My method stumbles right on the first line
Loader.load(fftw3.class);

```
Error
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load fftw3f: findLibrary returned null
```

I have imported `import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;` and `import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.fftw3.*;`. The second import by the way is highlighted as anused.

It is obvious that compiler does not see the library because of unknown to me reason.
Definitely I've missed something and more interaction with AS are demanded.

Can somebody more experienced give any kind of tutorial of adding library to project?

This is how my build.gradle file look like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.voicestopwatch"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw:3.3.4-1.1'
}
```

Concerning of including artefacts of android-arm and android-x86. I am not sure I have understood you. I really don't know what does process of including android-arm and android-x86 imply me to do.

After adding

```
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw:3.3.4-1.1:android-arm'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw:3.3.4-1.1:android-x86'
```

app crashes with these logs.
I have cutted logs because of limitations of symbols

```
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-14 21:03:49.024  11090-11090/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:49.204  10976-10976/? E/project﹕ extsdcard==/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/files
12-14 21:03:49.214  10976-10976/? E/project﹕ extsdcard==/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/files
12-14 21:03:49.274  11109-11109/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:49.804  10976-11088/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.H
12-14 21:03:49.814  10976-11088/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.b
12-14 21:03:49.814  10976-11088/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.b
12-14 21:03:50.044  10976-10976/? E/MainEntry﹕ App Start Time : 2502ms
12-14 21:03:51.034  11162-11162/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:51.084  10976-11176/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-14 21:03:51.714  11162-11162/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.assist.GsaVoiceInteractionSession_MembersInjector.al
12-14 21:03:51.724  11162-11162/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.gsa.j.d', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.j.f.al
12-14 21:03:51.974  11162-11195/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.e.K
12-14 21:03:51.994  11162-11195/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.e.c
12-14 21:03:52.064  11162-11191/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.UserHandleCompat$1.aD
12-14 21:03:52.064  11162-11191/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.co.cy
12-14 21:03:52.314    658-11213/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
12-14 21:03:52.334  11215-11215/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:52.954  10949-10949/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.icing.service.f.a
12-14 21:03:53.064  11215-11232/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method gqa.a
12-14 21:03:53.064  11215-11232/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method gqa.a
12-14 21:03:53.094  10949-10949/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.nb.a
12-14 21:03:53.104  10949-10949/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.nb.p
12-14 21:03:53.184  10949-10949/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.common.j.c', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.j.b.a
12-14 21:03:53.194    2909-2915/? E/dalvikvm﹕ No free temp registers
12-14 21:03:53.194    2909-2915/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Jit: aborting trace compilation, reverting to interpreter
12-14 21:03:53.314  10949-11229/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.icing.b.g.a
12-14 21:03:53.374  11215-11242/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) statement aborts at 1: [PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE;]
12-14 21:03:53.444  11248-11248/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:53.664  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Array storage bad crc 43683949 vs 4165082034
12-14 21:03:53.664  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Array storage bad crc 638625992 vs 433470135
12-14 21:03:53.714  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Array storage bad crc 1998651001 vs 2708843988
12-14 21:03:53.714  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Trie mmap suffix failed
12-14 21:03:54.304  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Lite index crc check failed: 3461100273 vs 3626299967
12-14 21:03:55.164      602-602/? E/wpa_supplicant﹕ wpa_driver_nl80211_driver_cmd: failed to issue private commands
12-14 21:03:55.324    446-13401/? E/Process﹕ Error getting pid for '0'
12-14 21:03:55.564  11306-11306/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:56.244  11324-11324/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:56.724    4100-4100/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
12-14 21:03:56.814  11351-11351/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:03:57.324  10949-11365/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.lockbox.LockboxService.a
12-14 21:03:57.534  11351-11351/? E/SubDex﹕ SubDex Config : .dex 2
12-14 21:03:58.614  11351-11351/? E/project﹕ extsdcard==/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/files
12-14 21:03:58.654  11351-11351/? E/project﹕ extsdcard==/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.cleanmaster.mguard/files
12-14 21:03:58.654      446-456/? E/WifiService﹕ Multicaster binderDied
12-14 21:03:58.994  11351-11351/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.H
12-14 21:03:58.994  11351-11351/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.b
12-14 21:03:58.994  11351-11351/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.cleanmaster.applocklib.b.d.b
12-14 21:03:59.084  11351-11351/? E/MainEntry﹕ App Start Time : 1572ms
12-14 21:03:59.404  11351-11420/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
12-14 21:04:00.104  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.google/maxwork82%40gmail.com
12-14 21:04:00.114  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus suggest_query
12-14 21:04:00.264  11430-11430/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:04:00.644  11430-11441/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.aG.a
12-14 21:04:00.654  11430-11441/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.aG.a
12-14 21:04:00.894  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp
12-14 21:04:00.904  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.vkontakte.account/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD
12-14 21:04:00.904  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.sonyericsson.localcontacts/Phone%20contacts
12-14 21:04:00.904  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.facebook.auth.login/%2B79242091115
12-14 21:04:00.954  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.sonyericsson.updatecenter.account.default/user%40updatecenter
12-14 21:04:00.954  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.viber.voip/%2B79242091115
12-14 21:04:00.954  10949-11229/? E/Icing﹕ Aborting indexing of corpus messages/com.sonyericsson.sdncontacts/SDN%20contacts
12-14 21:04:21.824      658-658/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [PowerConnectionProducer]Could not write powerInfo=Plug state: 2 BatteryLevel: 0.26, status=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
12-14 21:04:44.924  10828-10828/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3647)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   172 could not load needed library 'libfftw3f.so.3' for 'libjnifftw3.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libfftw3f.so.3' not found)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:438)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.fftw3.<clinit>(fftw3.java:10)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:429)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.fftw3.<clinit>(fftw3.java:10)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 21:04:45.154      923-923/? E/libEGL﹕ eglSetBlobCacheFuncsANDROID resulted in an error: 0x300c
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ Failed to call ioctl MSMFB_OVERLAY_SET err=Operation not permitted
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ MdpCtrl failed to setOverlay, restoring last known good ov info
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ == Bad OVInfo is:  mdp_overlay z=1 fg=0 alpha=255 mask=-1 flags=0x860000 id=-1
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ src msmfb_img w=736 h=1280 format=12 MDP_RGBA_8888
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ src_rect mdp_rect x=0 y=50 w=720 h=1230
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ dst_rect mdp_rect x=0 y=50 w=720 h=1230
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ user_data user_data cnt=8
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=0 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=1 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=2 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=3 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=4 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=5 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=6 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=7 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ == Last good known OVInfo is:  mdp_overlay z=0 fg=0 alpha=0 mask=0 flags=0x0 id=-1
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ src msmfb_img w=0 h=0 format=0 MDP_RGB_565
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ src_rect mdp_rect x=0 y=0 w=0 h=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ dst_rect mdp_rect x=0 y=0 w=0 h=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ user_data user_data cnt=8
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=0 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=1 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=2 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=3 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=4 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=5 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=6 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ i=7 val=0
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ MdpCtrl Lkgo ov has id -1, will not restore
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ Ctrl commit failed set overlay
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ OverlayImpl p0 failed to commit
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/overlay﹕ Overlay commit failed
12-14 21:04:45.374      171-357/? E/hwcomposer﹕ prepare: commit failed
12-14 21:05:13.124  11522-11522/com.example.android.voicestopwatch E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:05:18.574  11549-11549/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-14 21:06:13.934  11522-11522/com.example.android.voicestopwatch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3647)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   172 could not load needed library 'libfftw3f.so.3' for 'libjnifftw3.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libfftw3f.so.3' not found)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:438)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.fftw3.<clinit>(fftw3.java:10)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:597)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:429)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.fftw3.<clinit>(fftw3.java:10)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
            at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
            at com.example.android.voicestopwatch.SettingsActivity.fourie(SettingsActivity.java:544)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3642)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4147)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17161)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 21:08:09.064      658-658/? E/ctxmgr﹕ [PowerConnectionProducer]Could not write powerInfo=Plug state: 2 BatteryLevel: 0.27, status=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
```

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file ?

Comment: How did you include the `android-arm` and `android-x86` artifacts?

Comment: I see, `libfftw3.so` was linked with a version and Android doesn't support that. I'll have to fix that. Could you report an issue so I don't forget? Thanks

Comment: @Samuel Audet I definitly will. When do you want me to notify you?

Comment: Right away, open an issue, on GitHub, with all the info above, if possible.

Comment: @Samuel Audet I did it. Page is on my screen.

Comment: I don't see it in the list: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues

Comment: I have opened an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two dependencies should do the trick:

```
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw:3.3.4-1.1:android-arm'
compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw:3.3.4-1.1:android-x86'
```

Comment: As I suppose I had to add these lines into "build.gradle file" into "dependencies". Didn't work. Crushes on the same line. Nevertheless, mistakes are differ. "Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null" and "     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   172 could not load needed library 'libfftw3f.so.3' for 'libjnifftw3.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'libfftw3f.so.3' not found)
" is the privious

Comment: @МаксимГолендухин Could you check what you get in the log? It might tell us something more interesting, thanks.

Comment: Could you try with that line:

    compile 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:fftw-platform:3.3.5-1.3'